clr.AddReference throws System.OutOfMemoryException
I am using pythonnet 3.0.4 to call a function in a .NET dll (c#) from python. On my virtual machine this works fine, however, on Windows Server 2019 I get a System.OutOfMemoryException on the call to clr.AddReference().
I'm using python 3.12.4. First in my py script I am setting the path where the .NET dll resides, then I import clr:
sys.path.append(r'C:\PythonScripts')
import clr

Next I'm forcing use of TLS1.2 to avoid a security exception within the actual .NET functions. IDK if this is causing my issue, but figured it's worth mentioning.
clr.AddReference("System")
clr.AddReference("System.Net")
from System.Net import SecurityProtocolType, ServicePointManager
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

Then, my AddReference call which fails:
clr.AddReference('_mydll')

The error is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_python.py", line 301, in <module>
    clr.AddReference('_mydll')
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)

   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)

   at Python.Runtime.AssemblyManager.LoadAssemblyPath(String name)

   at Python.Runtime.CLRModule.AddReference(String name)

I have added the path of the dll to the Windows server's path environment variable.
I have also added a PYTHONNET environment variable and set it to 'netfx'.
And I've been all over google without finding any answers. Any help would be much appreciated.
